# How can i remove lines from a file when a string appears on multiple lines?

Tags: awk, sed, sort, uniq

I have a file that has 2 columns like the following:

```
apple pear
banana pizza
spoon fork
pizza plate
sausage egg
```

If a word appears on multiple lines i want to delete all lines that the repeating word appears, as you can see 'pizza' appears twice so 2 lines should be deleted, the following is the required output:

```
apple pear
spoon fork
sausage egg
```

I am aware of using :

```
awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

However this only removes the lines when the string appears in one column, i require a command that will check both columns. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Don't post the same question to multiple sites - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56926192/1745001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic two-step approach would be to create a list of non-unique words, and pipe that to `grep -v`.

For the first part, you could use `sort` and `uniq -d` (after serializing the words - perhaps with `tr`) or - if you want to continue to use `awk`, something like:

```
awk -vRS='[ \t\n]' 'seen[$0]++' file
```

which splits *records* on whitespace and prints those that *have* been seen before. So

```
$ awk -vRS='[ \t\n]' 'seen[$0]++' file | grep -Fvf- file
apple pear
spoon fork
sausage egg
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and for no space between `-v` and `RS=`. It'll also delete `grapefruit` if `grape` appears multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command

```
for i in `cat filename| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sort| uniq`; do j=`grep -c $i p.txt`; if [[ $j -eq 2 ]]; then sr=`echo $i`; else sed -n '/'$i'/p' p.txt| sed -n '/'$sr'/!p'; fi; done| awk '{if (!seen[$0]++)print $0}'
```

output

```
apple pear
sausage egg
spoon fork
```